# Is there any way to assign value to final variable from configuration?

Tags: java, variables, observer-pattern, java-ee-8

I have a method that will listen to the webhook queue and the method signature needs the webhook name as a final variable. This WEBHOOK_QUEUE variable needs to be different from the environment to the environment. (sandbox, production) Is there any way to solve this without changing the code In a different environment?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class WebhookEventObserver {
private static final String WEBHOOK_QUEUE = "V3-SANDBOX-WEBHOOK";


@Inject
private WebhookProcessor processor;

public void onMessage(@Observes @Queue(name = WEBHOOK_QUEUE) MessageEvent event) {
    logger.info("Received [{}] message from [{}]", event, WEBHOOK_QUEUE);
    processor.handleEvent(event);
}
}
```

Comment: If you can use Spring you should use @Profile, That's for your problem. If you do it without Spring look for a similar solution or create yourself solve through aspect or reflection. Spring's solve example you can see here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Comment: @DmitriiBq In what way is that comment a solution for making the value of the `static final` field `WEBHOOK_QUEUE` be initialized from an external source? Even with Profiles, you cannot initialize a `static final` field from the application properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Change the field from a constant to an injected configuration property:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class WebhookEventObserver {

    @Inject @ConfigurationValue("webhookQueue")
    private String webhookQueue;

    @Inject
    private WebhookProcessor processor;

    public void onMessage(@Observes MessageEvent event) {
        // check queue here
        logger.info("Received [{}] message from [{}]", event, webhookQueue);
        processor.handleEvent(event);
    }
}
```

You can't do the `@Queue(name = WEBHOOK_QUEUE)` with a dynamic queue name, so remove that event qualifier, and add logic to check it.

Don't know what `MessageEvent` is, so don't know how to check the queue of the event.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the exact behaviour without modifying code. however you can do this just removing the static final constant. directly replace the constant with property value `@Value("${webhookQueue}")`. Here is an example:

```
public void onMessage(@Observes @Queue(name =@Value("${webhookQueue}")) MessageEvent event)
```

On each of those property file provide appropriate value for `webhookQueue`.

Comment: which library has this @Value annotation, I am not using the spring framework only java ee is used in the project.